# Can a particle anti-particle pair be created with initial particles conserved?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, pair-production

Is it possible to have a particle collision between 2 particles, have those 2 particles structures conserved, but also create a particle-antiparticle pair in the process? For example, you have a Pion and Proton collide, those same 2 particles leave the collision, but the loss in energy gets transformed into a particle-antiparticle pair (kaon, anti-kaon for example)?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely yes. I would stay away from "dirty/messy" hadrons, and [look at](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.094023) rare four lepton decays of vector mesons, such as
$$
e^+e^-\to J/\psi \to \gamma^*\to e^+e^- \mu^+ \mu^- .
$$
[image]

Why?